# Is it possible to "go to next highlight in solution"?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

With ReSharper, I can "go to next error in solution", but it seems that "go to next highlight" is limited to the currently open file only.  Is this correct, or is it possible to "go to next highlight in solution"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about keyboard shortcut **ReSharper.GoToNrxtErrorInSolution**

(tools/options/keyboard, then enter "NextError" to easy find)

Comment: This appears to only go to the next error in the solution, not to the next highlight.